# Trigger email alerts in TFS 2015 on Test Case outcome analysis owner assignment

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-alerts

I had a user ask there was a special rule or filed for email alerts to trigger when test case results analysis owner is assigned. Or is that just a simple trigger on work item being assigned?

Comment: It is as simple as you think. Configure an alert on Work Item Change, Type Test Case.

Comment: Just checked and the Analysis field isn't a core field, so alerts will only work "When the field changes", for more detailed alerts, you'll need to setup a custom service hook or use something like the TFS Aggregator's SendMail option. https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator

Answer (score 0):

For TFS alter, we **could not select the specific field in work item as a filter**.

Take a look at the official tutorial-- [Set alerts, get notified when changes occur](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/alerts-and-notifications?view=tfs-2017)

Test case is a kind of work item. As a workaround, you could simply select work item change alter template to achieve this, select  test  case.

If you want to dig into specific field of work item to trigger a custom alert, you could try to use the extension--[*TFS Aggregator*](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/)  mentioned by jessehouwing in the comment.